# IntelliJ IDEA: how to fix broken font display?

Tags: intellij-idea

Unable to read the language. How to set it to english ?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is not with the language, but with some broken font mapping on your system. The workaround is to change IDE font. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to access the Settings dialog, open the second entry from the top and set some font here:

[image: font]

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue with IntelliJ Community Edition, version 2019 2.
Initially the only way I could get the "normal" IntelliJ charset mapping to persist after closing and reopening is go to **Settings > Appearance & Behaviours > Appearance**  and then to UNCHECK **Use Custom Font** and allow the built-in defaults to be applied.

Later I discovered that I could use all custom fonts except my favorite, Open Sans.
Somehow selecting and applying this font only worked for the remainder of the IntelliJ session. If IntelliJ was closed and reopened, the character mapping was altered in both the Settings page and in the IDE. Each character was represented by the next character alphabetically, e.g. Open Sans ==> Pqdo Tbot

[image]

Notice that the first letter of the menus (which has a separate formatting as it's underlined) remains the same while the remainder of the menu title is ampped to the next letter in the alphabet.

[image]

The question thus arises: why is Open Sans showing this change of character mapping while other fonts do not ?