# installing intellij on remote redhat 7 server, can't read instructions because character encoding problems

Tags: intellij-idea, redhat, xming

So im trying to install intellij idea to my remote redhat 7 server, and im trying to access it via Xming from my local PC with windows on.

Problem is that idea.sh starts, but the character encoding is messed up.
Would love to hear some suggetions for solving this problem!

PS.: attaching some images with details
[intellij encoding problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqSCK.png)
[java jdk+jre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMHTw.png)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46388106/104891.